# Split Folders Python for imbalanced number for files issue to keep fixed number of files for training set

Tags: python, split, directory, subdirectory

First of all, let me admire your efforts of developer for https://github.com/jfilter/split-folders making our lives so easy by developing this very handy tool. However, there is problem for imbalanced number of files in folders. In my case I want to keep exactly 200 files for training and rest for the test/validation regardless of how many files left for test/validation. If I do so following your code guidelines;

To only split into training and validation set, use a single number to `fixed`, i.e., `10`.

I got the following assertion error. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 7
> 8 #no_files
> ----> 9 sp.fixed(data_dir, output=output_dir, seed=13, fixed=200, oversample=False, group_prefix=None) # default values
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/splitfolders/split.py in
> fixed(input, output, seed, fixed, oversample, group_prefix)
> 96         fixed = fixed
> 97
> ---> 98     assert len(fixed) in (1, 2)
> 99
> 100     if tqdm_is_installed:
>
> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

My code is as follow:

```
splitfolders.fixed(data_dir, output=output_dir, seed=13, fixed=200, oversample=False, group_prefix=None) # default values
```

Comment: splitfolders.fixed(data_dir, output=output_dir, seed=13, fixed=200, oversample=False, group_prefix=None) # default values